# Sass math.div function is undefined in angular app, but is defined in angular lib

Tags: angular, sass

I need to use [Sass math.div](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/math#div) function in my angular application. Here is the example of my SCSS code:

```
@use "sass:math";

div {
  min-height: math.div(100, 2);
}
```

I created the angular application using `ng new my-application` command. Also I created a library in the application using `ng generate library my-lib` command.

The SCSS code with `math.div` works fine in the library. If I put the SCSS code in `projects/my-lib/src/lib/my-lib.component.scss` and run `ng build my-lib` then the library will build successfully.

But if I put the SCSS code in src folder, for example `src/app/app.component.scss` and run command `ng build` then I get this error:

```
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined function.
  ╷
4 │   min-height: math.div(100, 2);
  │                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\app\app.component.scss 4:17  root stylesheet
```

`math.div` function [is available in sass since 1.33.0](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/math#pow), so I think the problem is that angular app has different sass version from angular lib for some reason. But I don't know how to fix it.

For example `min-height: math.pow(10, 2);` works fine in the app. [math.pow is available since 1.25.0](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/math#pow)

Comment: I faced a similar issue, it had to do with my Node version being outdated. Simply running `nvm use node` (or updating node) in the command line will bump Node to the most recent version which Dart sass expects to be able to use `math.div()`.

Comment: `math.div()` was introduced in Sass `1.33.0`. https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In your  `package-lock.json` file you have two components related to sass:
`sass` itself and `sass-loader`. it would look something like this which represent already installed packages:

```
 "sass": {
  "version": "1.22.2",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/sass/-/sass-1.22.2.tgz",
},
"sass-loader": {
  "version": "7.1.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/sass-loader/-/sass-loader-7.1.0.tgz"
}
```

Can you bump up the version and place `sass` with  value `^1.33.0` in `package.json` (Which controls packages to be installed) under `dependencies`  and `sass-loader` with  value `12.0.0` and re-run `npm install` after saving.

Comment: There were sass 1.27.0 and sass-loader 10.0.5 in package-lock.json. I added "sass": "^1.33.0", "sass-loader": "12.0.0" in package.json dependencies and ran npm install but it did't help. Still get the error Undefined function.

Comment: And what are current versions in `package-lock.json`?

Comment: @angular-devkit/build-angular has dependencies: sass 1.27.0, sass-loader 10.0.5.


In root dependencies: sass 1.34.1, sass-loader 12.0.0

Comment: Well it's questionable practice to manually override angular's dependencies but can you try to give same values to `sass` and `sass-loader` under  `build-angular`

Comment: yes, it helps. If I manually change package-lock.json and run npm install then there is no error "Undefined function". I get another error: "Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function". It looks like @angular-devkit\build-angular really needs this old sass version

Comment: If that's the case maybe you can try to notify angular team on github?

Answer (score 4):

Changing the version of the `sass` package in the `package.json` file from `^1.26.5` to `^1.32.13` fixed the problem for me (Vue CLI app with TypeScript and SSR).

Furthermore, updating the `sass-loader` package (as mentioned in [Beka Kalandadze's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67858178/11869579) above) caused my application to brake.

Comment: This issue is a breaking change done since Sass `1.33.0`. https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div. `npm install sass@1.33.0` would do.

Comment: @m4heshd Thanks, this is really fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For my angular & scss project, changing `@use 'sass:math'` to `@use 'sass:math' as math;` helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using npm 8.19.2 review the "overrides" option. I solved the same problem this way.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides

```
    "overrides": {
        "sass": "1.55.0"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using `sass` not `node-sass` or other flavors. Also, as the others mentioned, make sure your `sass` version is higher than `v1.33.0`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I need to change the `sass` version to `1.33.0` in the `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`.

If I change the `sass-loader` version to `12.0.0`, I'll get the error `Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js): TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function`.

Because `@angular-devkit/build-angular` uses `webpack@4.44.2` which is not compatible with `sass-loader@12.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, what helped is upgrading to these versions -
"sass": "^1.59.3",   
"sass-loader": "^13.2.1"

Also, in my case, the global sass version was lower than my angular project. So I had to upgrade that as well.
npm i sass@^1.59.3 -g

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything obvious that was posted here.
My `sass` and `sass-loader` were up to date with versions higher than what others reported in their answers.

**Cause:**
I had `node-sass` installed with `sass` and `sass-loader`. After removing `node-sass` and reinstalling `sass` everything worked.

```
npm remove node-sass
npm install sass
```

Answer (score -5):

Remove math.div call:

```
min-height:    math.div(100, 2);

min-height:    (100 / 2); // this solves the problem
```

Comment: Please use your commenting privilege to ask clarification questions.

Comment: I am not expert in SCSS but it seems that there is a breaking change and usage as / for division is deprecated as it will be only a separator in next versions. I don't understand it well so I can't tell but it seems to me that the proposed answer should be avoided https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div

Comment: This is indeed deprecated and `math.div` solves a deprecation issue, removing it just moves the problem to the future.